# Converting Maven to Gradle: Replace tokens during Android build

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm fairly new the Gradle so this may be just a misunderstand of the underlying mechanisms. I'm trying to convert a Maven build to Gradle. I got it to build, and the only thing missing is replacing tokens/variables in some resource files.

The Maven code looks like this:

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/res</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/res</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.cfg</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/res</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/res</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.psd</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.cfg</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/assets</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/assets</targetPath>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
                <include>**/*.properties</include>
                <include>**/*.cfg</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/assets</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/assets</targetPath>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.psd</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.cfg</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <!-- PLUGINS -->
</build>
```

Now i want to have the same thing in Gradle. I don't need different variants and flavors. Also i'm happy with the default folder structure and don't want to redefine it unless it's really needed. All i could come up with was

```
task copyFiles(type: Copy) {
    from('src/main/res/') {
        exclude '**/*.psd'
        exclude '**/*.xml'
        exclude '**/*.properties'
        exclude '**/*.cfg'
    }
    from('src/main/res/') {
        include '**/*.xml'
        include '**/*.properties'
        include '**/*.cfg'
        expand(project.properties)
    }
    from('src/main/assets/') {
        exclude '**/*.psd'
        exclude '**/*.xml'
        exclude '**/*.properties'
        exclude '**/*.cfg'
    }
    from('src/main/assets/') {
        include '**/*.xml'
        include '**/*.properties'
        include '**/*.cfg'
        expand(project.properties)
    }
    into { getDestinationDir() }
}
preBuild.dependsOn copyFiles
```

The properties are defined in gradle.properties. I thought that getDestinationDir() would copy it to the default directory (where it would be put without messing with the copy task) but it results in a StackOverflow.

Example of file where I would like to replace tokens:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wearableApp package="${myproject.package}">
    <versionCode>7</versionCode>
    <versionName>${project.version}</versionName>
    <rawPathResId>myproject_wear</rawPathResId>
</wearableApp>
```

and

```
mode.release=${moderelease}
common.version=${projectversion}
```

I tried about 8 hours to get this to work, but now I don't know what to try anymore so any help is appreciated.